# Define Dynamic type to array in typescript

Tags: arrays, typescript, initialization

I have an class which contain array.

```
let object=new DynamicARRAY()
object.add(12)
object.add("google") // This should not allowed

let object=new DynamicARRAY()
object.add("google")
object.add(12) // This should not allowed
```

once i set type of and array how it can maintain type of that array.

i have some thing like that

```
class DynamicArray {
    add(value:string):Array<number>
    add(value:number):Array<string>

    add<T>(value:T):Array<T> {
        let collection = new Array<T>()        
        collection.push(value)
        return collection
    }   
}
```

but not show how i can move collection in class level and it maintain its type.

Need just hint on right direction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want is to make your class [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-classes) and then constrain you class method to use that generic type.

```
class DynamicArray<T> {
    add(value:T):Array<T> {
        let collection = new Array<T>()        
        collection.push(value)
        return collection
    }   
}
```

When using the class you specify what type it will hold

```
const array = new DynamicArray<string>();
array.add('foo');
array.add(12); // will fail
```

The only way I can think of having a generic entry point would be a static class which instantiate a generic typed class.

```
class TypedArray<T> {
    private items: T[] = [];

    add(value: T): this {
        this.items.push(value);

        return this;
    }
}

class DynamicArray {
    static add<T>(value:T): TypedArray<T> {
        let collection = new TypedArray<T>()        
        collection.add(value);

        return collection
    }   
}

const array = DynamicArray.add('foo');
array.add('bar');
array.add(12); // fails
```

Comment: Yes you are right but point is i dont want to set type,
It should be some how set auto automatic 
const array = new DynamicArray();
array.add('foo');
array.add(12); // will fail

Comment: Your example is fundamentally wrong, it returns an array which you don't use. Correct usage would be array.add('foo').push(12); // which will fail.

If you'd look what's in `array` after both of your `add()` you'd see that it's an empty object

Comment: Yes @opex i know that but example is not perfect but i just put it to show what i mean. I could not found any solution to this issue as well. 

your example is same as we add type an array. 
what we are looking right now is some kind of lat init of collection

Comment: You cannot change the type of a variable after it's been created. `array` is of type `DynamicArray` which contains a method to add values of arbitrary type. That will not change just because you call `add()` on `array`, it will still have the type `DynamicArray`